# Why is values.length = 2 in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the piece of code. I would like to know why values.length = 2 when I have 1 header and 1 row in the document. The range has height 1 because it start is the second row, so why 2?

```
function pushToCalendar() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('scheduler');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,9);
  var values = range.getValues();   
  var updateRange = sheet.getRange('scheduler!J1'); 
  var calendar =     CalendarApp.getCalendarById('rrgfkvm77h6gd6h0mcu1f701os@group.calendar.google.com')
  updateRange.setFontColor('red');

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) {            
      if (values[i][4] != '●') {                       
        var newEventTitle = values[i][0];
        var newEvent = calendar.createEvent(newEventTitle, 
             new Date(values[i][7]),
             new Date(values[i][8])); 
        var newEventId = newEvent.getId();
        sheet.getRange(i+2,6).setValue('●');
        sheet.getRange(i+2,7).setValue(newEventId);  
      }
  }

  updateRange.setFontColor('white');
}
```

Comment: `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`  How big is 'lastRow' ? I would think values.length is much larger than 2...  Are all 9 columns in your first row of data populated?

Comment: Not sure why you are putting -1 on the values.length as you are already skipping the header row. You grab data at row two. 
I would try changing this: `var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,9);` to `var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),9);`
it would be good if you can share a sample of your data you're working from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,9);
```

Should be

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow - 1,9);
// -1 being the number of header rows
```

To remove the header row from the number of rows. The third argument indicates the number of rows to include in the range, not the ending row(lastRow).

You must subtract from lastRow any rows proceeding the data that should not be included.

You will then need to change

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) {
```

To

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
```